# Pandas changes index datatype

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series `normal_row` which index values are:

```
Int64Index([  1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10,
            ...
            910, 911, 912, 913, 914, 915, 916, 917, 918, 919],
           dtype='int64', length=919)
```

I have a dataframe `resultp`

```
resultp.index
```

which returns

```
Int64Index([  1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10,
            ...
            910, 911, 912, 913, 914, 915, 916, 917, 918, 919],
           dtype='int64', length=919)
```

however

```
resultp.loc[14].index
```

returns

```
Index([u'1', u'2', u'3', u'4', u'5', u'6', u'7', u'8', u'9', u'10',
       ...
       u'910', u'911', u'912', u'913', u'914', u'915', u'916', u'917', u'918',
       u'919'],
      dtype='object', length=919)
```

This is creating issues becasue when

```
resultp.mul(normal_row, axis = 1)
```

returns a dataframe full of 'NaN' values. Also the shape of the dataframe changes from `(919,919)` to `(919,1838)`

which seems to appear is because the index types changes during the operation. How can this be fixed? and why does pandas keeps changing the index types, shouldn't the index types remain the same as the original index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resultp.loc[14].index`  are strings.  When you call `loc[14]` that returns the row with the index value of `14`.  This ends up being a series object whose index is equal to the columns of `resultp`

```
Index([u'1', u'2', u'3', u'4', u'5', u'6', u'7', u'8', u'9', u'10',
       ...
       u'910', u'911', u'912', u'913', u'914', u'915', u'916', u'917', u'918',
       u'919'],
      dtype='object', length=919)
```

This indicates that the columns are strings.

---

Consider the following objects

```
idx = pd.RangeIndex(0, 5)
col = idx.astype(str)
resultp = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 5), idx, col)
normal_row = pd.Series(np.random.rand(5), resultp.index)
```

Note that `col` looks the same as `idx` but is type `str`

```
print(resultp)

          0         1         2         3         4
0  0.242878  0.995860  0.486782  0.601954  0.500455
1  0.015091  0.173417  0.508923  0.152233  0.673011
2  0.022210  0.842158  0.302539  0.408297  0.983856
3  0.978881  0.760028  0.254995  0.610134  0.247800
4  0.233714  0.401079  0.984682  0.354219  0.816966
```

---

```
print(normal_row)

0    0.778379
1    0.019352
2    0.583937
3    0.227633
4    0.646096
dtype: float64
```

---

Because `resultp.columns` are strings, this multiplication comes back as `NaN`s

```
resultp.mul(normal_row, axis=1)

    0   1   2   3   4   0   1   2   3   4
0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
4 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

---

You need to cast the `resultp.columns` as `int`

```
resultp.columns = resultp.columns.astype(int)
```

Then multiply

```
resultp.mul(normal_row, axis=1)

          0         1         2         3         4
0  0.305954  0.079327  0.351183  0.588635  0.209578
1  0.136023  0.152232  0.443796  0.493444  0.678651
2  0.411359  0.267142  0.202791  0.327760  0.307422
3  0.399191  0.225889  0.130076  0.147862  0.038032
4  0.039647  0.058929  0.358210  0.684927  0.180250
```

Comment: I need to align the normal row index with the column value which goes from 1 to 919. Also, why does the index type changes when `.loc` method is used?

Comment: @DanielJimenez I have updated my post.  Hopefully this helps

Comment: Yeah it think this was the issue. I guess im still learning how pandas work